# バーチャルボックスで作ったデータを削除してしまい、EaseUS Data Recovery Wizardで復元したものの、直し方が分かりません。

Tags: virtualbox

ワードプレスでサイトを制作しました、途中PCが重くなり、データを削除したところ、
必要なデータを削除してしまいました、その後データを復元し、再びバーチャルボックスを使用しましたが、復元したデータをどこに入れるべきか、また正しいファイルの読み込ませ方が分かりません、
ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

至急ですので、マルチポストです。
(https://teratail.com/questions/96xasizrcbovec)
([バーチャルボックスで作ったデータを削除してしまい、EaseUS Data Recovery Wizardで復元したものの、直し方が分かりません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88262/%e3%83%90%e3%83%bc%e3%83%81%e3%83%a3%e3%83%ab%e3%83%9c%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b9%e3%81%a7%e4%bd%9c%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%82%92%e5%89%8a%e9%99%a4%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%84-easeus-data-recovery-wizard%e3%81%a7%e5%be%a9%e5%85%83%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ae-%e7%9b%b4%e3%81%97%e6%96%b9%e3%81%8c%e5%88%86%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93))

終了コード :
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
コンポーネント:
MediumWrap
インターフェース:
IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}

仮想マシン"ko_default_1644500041559_15806"のセッションを開けませんでした。
エラー（詳細）

```
Could not open the medium '/Users/kei/VirtualBox VMs/ko_default_1644500041559_15806/ko_default_1644500041559_15806/box-disk001.vmdk'.
VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file '/Users/kei/VirtualBox VMs/ko_default_1644500041559_15806/ko_default_1644500041559_15806/box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).
```

今、/Users/kei/VirtualBox VMs/ko_default_1644500041559_15806/ko_default_1644500041559_15806/box-disk001.vmdk'.のファイルはディスクトップにあり、適切な場所（予想だとファイルブラザ）に入れようとしています。どうも入れられませんが、やってみます。もしやり方をご存じの方がいましたらお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

「Virtualboxに新規の仮想マシンを作成し、そのマシンに復元したvmdkを割り当てる」という、
https://qiita.com/keikkkk/questions/d0e24fdcfab411b592ed このURL にあるようにやれば解決できそうです。